# Variance of sum of 2 random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, variance

Suppose $X$ is a normally distributed variable with mean 0 and variance $k$. Let $Y$ be an independent random variable taking values $-1$ and $ +1$ with equal probabilities . 
Define 
$Z$ = $XY$+$X/Y$ 
Find variance of Z.

My take on this.

Z=$2X$    with probability $0.5$

=$-2X$    With probability $0.5$

And i was getting VAR(Z) =4$k$

Comment: Hint:  Note that $Z=2XY$.

Comment: Hi k is the variance of the the normally distributed variable @Robert Israel

Comment: How is $Z=2XY$ here is'nt Z= XY+X/Y i'm unable to understand this . @lulu

Comment: Note that $\frac 1Y = Y$.

Comment: @lulu because $Y$ takes the value $-1$ and $+1$ respectively so it's reciprocal does'nt get effected? Is this correct

Comment: Yes, exactly.  And now, of course, you have $\text {Var}(2XY)=4\text{Var} (XY)$ which should be a familiar problem.

Comment: Yeah so Var(2XY)=4Var(XY) where Y takes value -1 and 1 so variance of 4(XY) will be nothing but 4$k$?

Comment: Right.  And it is easy to compute the variance of the product of two independent variables.  And, yes, it just comes to $4k$.

Comment: @lulu thankyou so much!